# Auto-formatting currency fields in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am developing an Oracle Report. It has about 15 currency fields. The database columns from where these values are derived have datatype NUMBER(m,n).

I am formatting them in reports as follows:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(field1,'99,999,999.99') --field1 datatype NUMBER(8,2)
SELECT TO_CHAR(field2,'99,999,999,999.99') --field2 datatype NUMBER(11,2)
```

Is there a way for Oracle to auto-format the fields based on the datatype precision of the field?

Basically I want to prevent hard-coding the `'99,999,999.99'`format and let Oracle do that as it already knows the precision of the field.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for here are format masks.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(99999999.99,'FM9G999G999G999G990D00') from dual;
Output: 99,999,999.99

SELECT TO_CHAR(99999999999.99,'FM9G999G999G999G990D00') from dual;
Output: 99,999,999,999.99

SELECT TO_CHAR(123.54,'FM9G999G999G999G990D00') from dual;
Output: 123.54

SELECT TO_CHAR(18945.65,'FM9G999G999G999G990D00') from dual;
Output: 18,945.65
```

EDIT: To clarify the FM9G999G999G999G990 should handle up to the max precision while D00 the scale to tenth.

Comment: For readability reasons I like using actual commas, decimal points, and dolor signs: `SELECT TO_CHAR(99999990.00,'FM$9,999,999,999,990.00') FROM DUAL` what is the benefit to using G and D over literal characters?